# kodi.executebuiltin() not working in Kodi: Isengard

Tags: python, kodi

I have written a home automation script for controlling lights, music on kodi, and my TV.  I have everything working except for turning off the TV.  I have mapped my keyboard.xml file within kodi to recognize the "CECToggleState", and this works fine, but I would like to trigger this inside a python script.

In the past, one could import the xbmc module, then use the command "`xbmc.executebuiltin()`" to run built in kodi functions, like "`CECToggleState`".  The xbmc module has been replaced by the kodi module. I have seen examples where it is suggested that "`kodi.executebuiltin()`" can be used,  but the kodi module does not appear to actually support "`executebuiltin`".  When I try running this command in python, I get an error that reads:

`"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'executebuiltin'"`

Can anyone confirm that this is true, or offer what has replaced this command? Or, does anyone know of a good alternative to get the same effect -- ie, send "TV off" command programatically through HDMI CEC?

Answer (score 1):

```
import xbmc
xbmc.executebuiltin('XBMC.CECToggleState()')
```

This works in my python addon in Isengard.
To turn off TV use:

```
xbmc.executebuiltin('XBMC.CECStandby()')
```

or to turn on:

```
xbmc.executebuiltin('XBMC.CECActivateSource()')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write `xbmc.executebuitin("XBMC.CECToggleState()")`, not `kodi.executebuitin("XBMC.CECToggleState()")`, and please upgrade your kodi from isengard to a stable version (i.e, Kyrpton).